# Change in UINavigationBar's color

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am working on iOS 7 app. My navigation bar used to look as in the image below:

[image]

but after adding this piece of code

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

The navigation car color got darker as in the next image:.[image]

How do we let the navigation bar to stay brighter as in the first image while keeping the code above?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the translucent property of navigation bar is set to YES.

 Additionally, there is a system blur applied to all navigation bars. Under this setting, iOS 7 tends to desaturate the color of the bar.

**Difference Translucent settings**

[image: Difference Translucent settings]
**Setting Tint Color**
[image: Setting Tint Color]

**Turn off translucent setting**

[image: Turn off translucent setting]

**Put this code in appDelegate.m in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later


// To change the background color of navigation bar
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];

// To change the color of back button
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

}
```

Comment: this partially solves my question, but I dont want the uncontrolled change in UINavigationbar's color, which is my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

For iOS7, Navigation bar's color can changed by this few lines.

```
if(IS_IOS7){

    //Your color code
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:34.0/255.0 green:59.0/255.0 blue:135.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes
    = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, a navigation bar’s tintColor affects the color of the back indicator image, button titles, and button images. The barTintColor property affects the color of the bar itself. Additionally, navigation bars are translucent by default. Turning the translucency off or on does not affect buttons, since they do not have backgrounds.

add this code in your appdelegate

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yourColorCode]];

//optional 

        NSShadow *shadowObj = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadowObj.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadowObj.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                               [UIColor colorWithRed:205.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:45.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                               shadowObj, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                               [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:117/255.0f green:4/255.0f blue:32/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Comment: I know this property but how do I avoid the change in color when I have set one color?

Comment: Sorry i think you want to be change the color of navigationbar